# WebApi: Accept GET file in path

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working at creating a small authentification API for an already existing project. The idea is that all calls pass through this API that checks for an access token. It works for most of the cases except for when in the path there is any file extension

This works: localhost:26860/TranslationService/widgest/QuotationWidget

This doesn't: localhost:26860/TranslationService/widgest/QuotationWidget.js

This is my route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "{*uri}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Gateway", uri = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class GatewayController : ApiController
{
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string uri)
    {
     ....
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A work around is suffixing the URL with a slash e.g. localhost:26860/TranslationService/widgest/QuotationWidget.js/ instead of localhost:26860/TranslationService/widgest/QuotationWidget.js

Comment: do you get 404 error message?

Comment: @esiprogrammer, it is a 404 error message. "The resource cannot be found"

Comment: @acidbabies this worked! But I think we would need to change all the front end calls in order to make that work. Is there any easier solution in this case?

Comment: @Gunoi As stated hereunder as an answer by esiprogrammer you can add a HTTP handler like this:  `<add 
    name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" 
    path="/TranslationService/widgest/*" 
    verb="GET" 
    type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" 
/>`

Answer (score 0):

if you get 404 error message you should add `handler` configuration to handlers section in `system.webservice` section:

```
<add 
    name="jsFileExtension" 
    path="api/nav/*/*.js" 
    verb="GET" 
    type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" 
/>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this work only for .js files? Because this is just a gateway it needs to redirect all the traffic, no matter what path or files the user wants

Comment: @Gunoi it only wokrs fo `.js` file extension. you need to specify a handler for each extension